# Highlight my "@users' name" in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to highlight the username of a user when it's detected in a string like @login. Here's the code which doesn't seem to work:

```
function parse(string) {
    var regex = new RegExp('(\W|^)@('+username+')(\W|$)', 'i');
    return String(string).replace(regex, '<span class="label radius">@$2</span>');
}
```

And here's a jsfiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/2pmLT/3/

When I type my @login, it highlight it but only if it's the only text in the string: "@login haha" won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes. Also, you should also add $1 and $3, else you drop your spaces. Use a g-flag for multiple replaces

http://jsfiddle.net/7h8Aq/

```
function parse(string) {
    var regex = new RegExp('(\\W|^)@('+username+')(\\W|$)', 'ig');
    return string.replace(regex, '$1<span class="label radius">@$2</span>$3');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't even think about escaping.

Answer (score 0):

*[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/2pmLT/5/)* you go, you only need to replace certain instances, so there's no nee to match the whole string, you also need to specify the global `g` flag for regex:

```
function parse(text) {
    return text.replace(new RegExp('(@' + username + ')', 'g'), 
        '<span class="label radius">$1</span>');
}
```

Comment: Doing this will also highlight stuff like email@login.com which might be unwanted

Answer (score 0):

Consider [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2pmLT/7/) instance.

**HTML**

```
<div id="test-block">
    <div class='label'></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#test').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $('.label').text(parse($(this).val()));
});

function parse(myString) {
    var find = "(\W|^)@(" + username + ")(\W|$)";
    var regex = new RegExp(find, 'i');
    return myString.replace(regex, '@$2');   
}
```